# how to upload local user image and overlay onto flash video/animation

Tags: flash, apache-flex, image-processing

I want to create a custom video like the videos on jibjab, i.e allow a user to upload an image of their face and superimpose this onto a video of a character's face.

can anyone point me in the right direction on how to go about this? Any pointers would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do that, and I doubt any library could really help you, as none can detect face outlines with 100% accuracy. You'll have to do it by yourself, maybe this way:

1. Create a new movie clip
2. Put the video on a timeline of this movie clip
3. Create a shape with the same outline as the face in your video
4. Frame by frame, move, resize and rotate the shape so that it follows the face in the video

Once you have this working, just swap the shape with the user's face and you'll have your custom video.

Comment: thanks a bunch, do you know if there is any samples to allow a user to upload an image for use in the flash movie?

Comment: Sure, there are two ways: 1) Let them upload the image using `FileReference` or 2) capture it through the webcam using `Camera`.